# Why doesn't Javascript map function String.toLowerCase doesn't work in nodejs 6?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm going through the book Learning Javascript by Ethan Brown. There is an example on how to use the map function to convert all the elements in a array to lowercase like this:

```
const cart = [ { name: "Widget", price: 9.95 }, { name: "Gadget", price: 22.95 }];
const names = cart.map(x => x.name);
const lcNames = names.map(String.toLowerCase);
```

If I run this in the Firefox (v51) browser console, it works, however if I try to run this in nodejs v6.9.4 I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.map (native)
    at repl:1:27
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:96:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:21:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:346:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:545:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
```

If I change the lcNames assignment to the following for nodejs then it runs fine:

```
const lcNames = names.map(x => x.toLowerCase());
```

I checked the ES6 Javascript compatibility chart for node6 vs Firefox 50 and they both seem to support the same features. So why doesn't the code from the book work in nodejs?

Comment: `String.toLowerCase()` doesn't exist everywhere; it's not standard.

Comment: `String.prototype.toLowerCase` exists, as a method, not as a function. You shouldn't be able to do `map(String.toLowerCase)`, and `map(String.prototype.toLowerCase)` would apply `toLowerCase(str)` instead of `str.toLowerCase()`. You need a lambda, as you have in your last example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

```
names.map(String.toLowerCase);
```

works in Firefox because it has [*String generic methods*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_generic_methods) that include *toLowerCase* and are documented with the note:

> String generics are non-standard, deprecated and will get removed near
>   future. Note that you can not rely on them cross-browser without using
>   the shim that is provided below.

Most important is that they aren't part of ECMAScript, so likely not supported in other browsers. If you want to use it, you can conditionally add a pollyfill, though there is a shim for adding all the generic methods at [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_generic_methods).

```js
// Built-in support?
console.log('Has built-in String.toLowerCase? ' + (typeof String.toLowerCase == 'function'));

// Polyfill if not supported
if (!String.toLowerCase) {
  String.toLowerCase = function(s) {
    return String(s).toLowerCase();
  }
}

// Test it
console.log(['A','B','C'].map(String.toLowerCase))
```

Comment: Thanks. Although the author makes a brief mention about using Firefox in the beginning, there is no further mention of it until much later in the book. Everything up to this point could be run in the nodejs console and doesn't need to deal with web pages, which made it convenient. I guess I should keep using nodejs to detect when another bias like this comes up in the text.  But I think the author should have alerted the reader more, especially if they use this as a reference. Time for a book review.

Answer (score 1):

`String.toLowerCase` does not exist. However, `String.prototype.toLowerCase` does. But keep in mind that `this` would need to be set for that call to succeed, whereas `map` would *pass it as a parameter*. Hence, this is the most straightforward thing to do:

```
const lcNames = names.map(name => name.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: "*String.toLowerCase does not exist*" but it does in Firefox, so it exists in JavaScript. However, it's not part of ECMAScript.

Comment: It's not part of JavaScript _or_ ECMAScript, but is a non-standard extension from Firefox.

Comment: JavaScript™ is whatever Mozilla want it to be, so whatever is in Mozilla is in JavaScript. Per MDN: "[*The String instance methods are also available in Firefox as of JavaScript 1.6*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_generic_methods)". ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined on the prototype (`String.prototype.toLowerCase`), meaning that instances of the string type have access to the `toLowerCase` function.

That's why you can access that function via `const lcNames = names.map(x => x.toLowerCase());`.

This on the other hand works, because `isFinite` is not defined through the prototype, but on `Number` itself.

```
const prices = cart.map(x => x.price);
prices.map(Number.isFinite);
```

Comment: Although I already know what prototypes are in an OOP sense from other languages, they aren't explained for another 10 pages from this point. One of the reasons I'm actually reading this book is to brush up on my OO Javascript.